# Execute Observable by condition in Angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I would like to execute API call only when condition is `true` in `*ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn(); else anonymousUser"`:
However, the API call to the server is made even `auth.isLoggedIn()` returns false.

navbar.html:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn(); else anonymousUser">                  
    <li *ngIf="appUser$ | async as anUser">
        {{ anUser?.name }}
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

navbar.ts

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
    appUser$: Observable<AppUser>;      

    constructor(private userService: UserService,
                private auth: AuthService) {
    }

    async ngOnInit() {
        this.appUser$ = this.userService.get();     
    }
}
```

auth.service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    public isLoggedIn() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
    if (token !== 'undefined' && !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }    
}
```

user.service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    get(): Observable<AppUser> {
        return super.getById(localStorage.getItem('userId'))
            .pipe(map(s => ( {id: s.id, name: s['userName']
                              , isAdmin: s['isAdmin']})));
    }
}
```

Could you tell me how can I execute API call when only `auth.isLoggedIn()` returns `true`?

Comment: What is `auth.isLoggedIn()`? there is no object in your class. Please add more details. And also you need not add `async` keyword to `ngOnInit` hook

Comment: @AmitChigadani please, see my updated question

Comment: This doesn't seem reproducible imo. If I had to guess, I'd bet it has something to do with the `super.getById` implementation. Otherwise see if you can edit this so it's reproducible: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmxqhw

Comment: Are you sure you want to check `'undefined'` and not `undefined`?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm yes, you can check in console `typeof fooStr`

Comment: @Learner Yes it will. Just like any Observable. Once it's subscribed to it emits.

Comment: @Freddy yeah, you are right! I really don't know why it did not work in my sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider using the RxJS `filter()` operator (not to be confused with the JavaScript [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method). According to the [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html), it will

> Emit values that pass the provided condition.

Hence, this will ensure that the observable will only be completed only if the condition (`isLoggedIn` returns true) is passed.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.appUser$ = this.userService.get()
    .pipe(
      filter(auth.isLoggedIn()),
    );     
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! It works! Have a nice day! Thanks!:)